# C# getting a jagged array from a method call

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

I have a jagged array and it works fine in the `main` but if I try to put it in a method I'm unsure what to call. I've tried `load(data)` and return statements but I haven't had any luck.

```
public static void load() 
{
    try 
    {
        string[][] data = new[] {
            File.ReadAllLines(@"data\Month.txt"),
            File.ReadAllLines(@"data\Year.txt"),
            File.ReadAllLines(@"data\WS1_AF.txt"),
            File.ReadAllLines(@"data\WS1_Rain.txt"),
            File.ReadAllLines(@"data\WS1_Sun.txt"),
            File.ReadAllLines(@"data\WS1_TMin.txt"),
            File.ReadAllLines(@"data\WS1_TMax.txt"),
        };
        Console.WriteLine("Files have been found, press any key to continue");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    catch (Exception) {
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to find files... exiting");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you ACTUALLY trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to fetch the array from that method to another method. Transfering it between other methods

Comment: yes, but we don't understand your question.  are you trying to return data to another thing? then you need `public static string[][] load()` and `return data;` in your code.  otherwise we have no idea what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply return your array from the method and also change the return type of the `load` method to the same type as the array you're returning has (`void` means you're returning nothing). Also, it's better idea to handle the exceptions on the higher level:

```
public static string[][] load()
{
    string[][] data = new[]
    {
        File.ReadAllLines(@"data\Month.txt"),
        File.ReadAllLines(@"data\Year.txt"),
        File.ReadAllLines(@"data\WS1_AF.txt"),
        File.ReadAllLines(@"data\WS1_Rain.txt"),
        File.ReadAllLines(@"data\WS1_Sun.txt"),
        File.ReadAllLines(@"data\WS1_TMin.txt"),
        File.ReadAllLines(@"data\WS1_TMax.txt"),
    };

    return data;
}

public static void test()
{
    try
    {
        var data = load();

        Console.WriteLine("Files have been found, press any key to continue");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to find files... exiting");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your signature from `void` to the return type you expect to return and return your array.

```
public static string[][] load()
{
    try
    {
        string[][] data = new[]
        {
            File.ReadAllLines(@"data\Month.txt"),
            File.ReadAllLines(@"data\Year.txt"),
            File.ReadAllLines(@"data\WS1_AF.txt"),
            File.ReadAllLines(@"data\WS1_Rain.txt"),
            File.ReadAllLines(@"data\WS1_Sun.txt"),
            File.ReadAllLines(@"data\WS1_TMin.txt"),
            File.ReadAllLines(@"data\WS1_TMax.txt"),
        };
        Console.WriteLine("Files have been found, press any key to continue");
        Console.ReadKey();

        return data;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to find files... exiting");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note that you have to return something from your catch block as well since you are not rethrowing the exception. In this case, return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider also a more modular approach with path and filename array

```
class Program
{
    public static string[][] ReadFiles(string folder, params string[] files)
    {
        return files.Select((fn) => File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(folder, fn))).ToArray();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var data = ReadFiles(@"data", 
            "Month.txt",
            "Year.txt",
            "WS1_AF.txt",
            "WS1_Rain.txt",
            "WS1_Sun.txt",
            "WS1_TMin.txt",
            "WS1_TMax.txt" );
    }
}
```

**Appendix**

Try also not to hard code any absolute paths, but use the special folder enumeration. For example:

```
var folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```